# how to get exact two digits after decimal point in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, nsdecimalnumber

I want the exact 2 digits after the decimal point. I tried the `toFixed(2)` function but it returns rounded off 2 digits. Here is my Code it returns `18.70` but I want `18.69`extract number

```
rim_weight = (23* 36 *70);
rim_weight = rim_weight/3100; // retuns 18.69677419354839
rim_weight = rim_weight.toFixed(2); // returns 18.70
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to truncate the number to two decimal places, first divide by 31, convert to an integral value using `Math.floor` and then divide by 100:

```js
rim_weight = (23 * 36 * 70);
rim_weight = Math.floor(rim_weight / 31);
rim_weight = rim_weight / 100;
console.log(rim_weight);
```

Comment: @MuhammadHaris Can I ask why you decided to unaccept this answer? Did you find a problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

just convert it to string then match the number up to the second place